# Explain C code snippet: preprocessor + printf =?

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor

The output for this code snippet is `%s is a string is a string`. Please explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define scanf "%s is a string"

int main()
{
    printf(scanf, scanf);  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What exactly do you want us to explain? Subsititute the macro and get

```
printf("%s is a string", "%s is a string");
```

The rest is the expected normal everyday behavior of `printf`.

P.S. `#define scanf ...`???

Comment: why is the output '%s is a string is a string' ?

Comment: @Vish: Because that's how `printf` works and that's what `printf` does. When you read the description of `printf` in your favorite C book or doc, was there something you couldn't understand?

Comment: @Vish: Think of it this way.  The format string for the `printf()` call is `"%s is a string"`.  There's a `"%s"` format so it takes the corresponding argument and substitutes it as a string.  The first argument was the string `"%s is a string"`.  Putting it all together, `"[%s is a string] is a string"` is printed (brackets added for emphasis).

Comment: This is a classic "use-mention" distiction: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction "%s is a string" is itself a string, but it can also be *used* in the printf statement because it has the string-interpolation directive. The '%s' is a "hole" in the template that you can fill in with any string you want. You are then "filling it in" using itself (because it's a string)!

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor does a blind substitution to give:

```
printf("%s is a string","%s is a string");
```

The `%s` in the first argument is the format specifier for a string and is replaced with the 2nd argument. There is nothing special about the `%s` in the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is some rather bizarre code, but the output would be "%s is a string is a string" because scanf is expanded to "%s is a string" in both cases and then printf substitutes that in for the %s.

Answer (score 1):

printf("%s is a string","%s is a string");

I guess the confusion is what the printf will do with the second %s. 
To clear this, printf is not a recursive function. If you are printing a string and that string has any format-identifier it is not considered as format identifier. It is considered as plain string. So in this case the second "%s is a string" is just a plain string. %s in this string is not format-identifier.

If you had something like printf("%s %s is a string", "%s %s is a string"); 
Then yes you will get runtime error saying that printf is missing some argument.

Answer (score 0):

to understand this code,run the following statements one by one:-

```
printf("%s is a string","StRiNG");
printf("%s %s is a string","StRiNG");
printf("%s is a string","StRiNG","Hey");
```